# JS - called method is not a function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have object:

```
var devark = {
    init: function() {
        var obj = this;
        obj.assignHandlers();
    },
    assignHandlers: function() {
        var obj = this;
        document.getElementById("menu-toggler").onclick = obj.documentFunctions[0];
    },
    documentFunctions: [
        function() {
            toggleClass(this, "opened");
        }
    ]
};
```

on `window.load`, I am calling the `init` method. That works fine but when it calls another object method `assignHandlers`, it throws an error:

> [17:54:33.192] TypeError: obj.assignHandlers is not a function

Why is it?

Comment: Call  it like `window.onload = function() { devark.init(); };`. Learn how the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/kADvm/

Comment: @Bergi You rock !!!!! but what was the error for? What is the diff?

Comment: @tymeJV bcoz JSFiddle has called the object's method exactly as Bergi said. View the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Bergi said, it's a `this` value issue that can be solved by doing:

```
window.onload = function () {
    devark.init();
};
```

The difference between both ways is the value of `this` within the `init` function. To determine the natural value of `this`, look at the left-side of the `.` in a method call, such as `obj.someFn();`. Here the value of `this` within `someFn` will be `obj`. However, when you do `window.onload = devark.init;`, you can imagine the handler will later be invoke like `window.onload()`. Which means the value of `this` within the `onload` function, which is really the `init` function will be `window`, not `devark`.

You can also use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind a specific `this` value to a function.

```
window.onload = devark.init.bind(devark);
```

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar, I added an alternative way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I have seen it ;)